# Young measures for variational problems

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces, calculus-of-variations

I am learning that Young measures can be useful for variational problems. When a set of functions isn't compact in function space (so they don't have a convergent subsequence), we can associate those functions with Young measures, and then use a sort of compactness on the set of Young measures.

[Here](https://regularize.wordpress.com/2011/05/11/what-young-measures-can-tell-about-weak-convergence-of-non-linearly-distorted-functions/) is a nice explanation I found introducing Young measures and a version of Prohorov's theorem for Young measures.

It says that given a bounded sequence $u_n \in L^\infty(\Omega)$, the sequence of corresponding Young measures $\nu^n$ (which can be "sliced" into $\nu^n_x = \delta_{u_n(x)}$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$) has a convergent subsequence. Furthermore, the limit $\nu$ is also a Young measure.

My question is

- Is $\nu$ also of the form $\nu_x = \delta_{u(x)}$ for some function $u$? I want to say no (or maybe $u$ isn't $L^\infty$) because $L^\infty$ isn't compact.
- If not, then can we describe it other other than the most general definition of Young measure (stated in the link)?
- And if not, why is this useful for variational problems?

Comment: for the record, sec 4.3 in the book "variational analysis in sobolev and BV spaces" by attouch et al is very useful for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\Omega=(0,1)$ and $u_n(x) = \sin(n\pi x)$. Then the Young measure limit is
$$
\nu_x = \frac12 \delta_{-1} + \frac12 \delta_{+1}
$$
in the sense that
$$
\int_\Omega f( u_n(x))dx \to \frac 12 (f(-1) + f(1))
$$
for all continuous $f$.  This example is also discussed on the website you linked.

Why is this usefull for variational problems? Problems posed wrt Young measures have solutions under much weaker conditions. In addition, the Young measure minimum coincides with the infimum of the original problem.

Comment: Thank you! So in this example, the limiting Young measure corresponds to a function $u$ that is like some kind of Heaviside function that take values $\pm 1$ each on half of $\Omega$? My question is about whether the limiting function always corresponds to $L^\infty$ function (and if not, what kind of function it would be, is it unique, etc)

Comment: Here the limit is not a function: for each $x\in \Omega$, $\nu_x$ is a probability measure. The limit can be interpreted as: for all $x$, the limit is $+1$ or $-1$ with probability $0.5$.

Comment: oh, I see that! thank you very much